# Does MarkLogic resource extension's context variable contain the uri?

Tags: marklogic

I was reading the MarkLogic resource extension documentation (https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_21018) and I have a question.

In the table listing the parameters it states that the context parameter holds input information such as input type and URI. However, I have set up a a resource extension that should accept multiple documents and receive the `content-type`, but not the URI in the `$context` variable  (I printed the `$context` variable to log). I used the following syntax in my rest request:

```
--BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename"test1.xml
<data>testdata</testdata>
--BOUNDARY--
```

with a header of

```
Content-Type=multipart/mixed; boundary=BOUNDARY
```

Why does my URI does not show up here?

Interestingly, note that the Context Map Keys section (which is referred from the table with the context parameters description) does not list URI as a possible key. Furthermore, in the JavaScript example in the resource section the URI is constructed via an explicit url-parameter (i.e. `myresource?basename=test.xml`). This seems to suggest that the initial documentation (stating that you can get the URI from the `$context`) is in error. Is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the summary table in the documentation that mentions a uri property is correct for transforms but not for resource service extensions.

One workaround would be to construct an initial part that has a JSON document with an array of uris.  You could then iterate over the subsequent documents and the URI array in parallel.

Hoping that helps,